# Not able to install and update ubuntu 22.04 drivers using bootable ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, drivers, apt, nvidia, chroot

I was trying to install a software that was giving me some gpu errors so i decided to downgrade my nvidia driver from 535 to 525. While doing so I got error in additional drivers app in Ubuntu. So after that I did a reboot but this time there was no display.

Then I switched to open source driver nouveau that nvidia provides. With nouveau I was able to get the display back but Wi-Fi was not working and it I was not able to detect usb. I thought of using USB tethering to do sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, but I had no internet access due to Wi-Fi not working in Ubuntu.

The next time I rebooted, I again got black screen. Then I decided to install drivers by doing chroot from bootable Ubuntu 22.04. That’s where the problem comes. See the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo mount •-bind /dev/pts /mnt/ny_syster/dev/pts sudo: unable to allocate pty: No such device 
ubuntu@ubuntu:/S 1s -1 /dev/ptrx
    CrW-rW-rW- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5., 2 Oct 21 20:39 /dev/ptmx
ubuntu@ubuntu:/S sudo rm /dev/ptrx 
sudo: unable to allocate pty: No such device
```

As you can see above, I am not able to mount `/dev/pts`. When I chroot after this error and do sudo apt update I get the same: `sudo: unable to allocate pty: No such device`

To be more clear I took the following steps from the start:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/my_system
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p8 /mnt/my_system
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/my_system/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/my_system/sys
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/my_system/dev
sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/my_system/run

ubuntu@ubuntu: /$ sudo mount - -bind /run /mnt/my_System/run
ubuntu@buntu:/$ sudo chroot /mnt/my_system 
root@ubuntu: /# sudo apt update
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 999, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 999, should be 0 sudo: error in /etc/sudo.cont. , line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers polics
sudo: /us/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid o sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

exit 
chown root:root /etc/sudo.conf
sudo chown root:root /mnt/my_system/etc/sudo.conf
sudo chown root:root /mnt/my_system/usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
```

……..(Gave permission to other files like the above)

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/my_system/dev/pts
```

It says `sudo: unable to allocate pty: no such device`

After this I chroot and do sudo apt update which gives the same error.

Does anyone know how to run sudo apt update and upgrade from bootable Ubuntu 22.04 drive to download and update the drivers?